# I am going to the countryside

Tags: definite-article, zero-article

I am going to the countryside.

Is there any occasion where countryside would be used without "the", so it would go like: I am going to countryside, or something else?

Comment: Not that I can think of as a noun. Did you find such a usage somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no. You would never use "countryside" without "the".

If, however, "countryside" is a proper noun, you would.

For example, [this nursery](http://www.countrysideaustin.com/) is called "Countryside Nursery".

If you are telling someone you are going to this nursery, you would say:

> I'm going to Countryside Nursery.

If both you and the person you're speaking to are familiar with this place, you may refer to it with a shorthand version of the name, omitting "Nursery":

> John: *Which nursery are you going to?*
>   Beth: *I'm going to Countryside.*

But, as you can see, since it is a proper noun, "Countryside" should be capitalized.